# Individually color each data point in ggplot in a box and whisker plot with pre-chosen colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to plot box and whisker plots, where each data point is also plotted on top.

Here is my code currently:

```
df_3UTR_ext_colors <- read_excel(pathname_ext, sheet = "Sheet1", 
                                 col_types = c("text", "text", "text", 
                                               "numeric", "text", "text"))

# Plotting
allGenes_colors_simple <- ggplot(df_3UTR_ext_colors_simple, aes(Gene, Length) )

allGenes_colors_simple + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, aes(fill = Genus), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Genus), 
             size = 2, shape = 21, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

This is the current output for that code:

[image: Output for above code]

I want to **color each dot individually according to the hex code that I have added to the data frame**.

Ideally, I want **each dot's color to be a variation of the color of its associated box** (example: all viruses making up the Henipavirus genus would be different shades of red). I have manually gone through and done this with the hex codes in the Color column in case that is the easiest way to do this.

I have tried many iterations of this to no avail. For example, within `geom_point()` I am using `aes(fill = Genus)`. If I instead sub that out for `aes(fill = Virus)` the result looks something like this:

[image: Switching to aes(fill = Virus) within geom_point().]

Obviously there are many problems here. One is that the palette runs out. This is likely easily fixable so I'm not overly concerned. Another is that suddenly the **data points are no longer in line with their associated box**, they start to stray. Additionally, this limits my manual control over the color of each individual point as well.

My feeling is that there are many easier ways with RColorBrewer to assign palettes to each Genus giving the viruses their own color (in fact, it was the process of manually going through color palettes that gave me the hex codes I manually added to the data frame). But I'm not overly worried about that if I can get `ggplot` to color each point individually based on my manually added colors.

Does anyone have any advice?

```
> dput(df_3UTR_ext_colors_simple)
structure(list(Genus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Henipavirus", 
"Morbillivirus", "Rubulavirus", "Respirovirus", "Avulavirus", 
"Aquaparamyxovirus", "Ferlavirus"), class = "factor"), Virus = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("HeV", "NiV", 
"CedV", "GhV", "MojV", "MeV", "CDV", "FeMV", "MuV", "HPIV-2", 
"PIV5", "SeV", "HPIV1", "HPIV3", "APMV-1_NDV", "APMV-3", "AsaPV", 
"FDLV"), class = "factor"), Gene = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("N", 
"P", "M", "F", "RBP", "RdRp"), class = "factor"), Length = c(568, 
469, 200, 418, 516, 67, 586, 469, 200, 412, 504, 67, 334, 192, 
408, 88, 139, 63, 238, 213, 314, 82, 68, 65, 164, 144, 455, 173, 
543, 50, 59, 72, 426, 137, 84, 176, 59, 72, 407, 132, 111, 65, 
47, 98, 333, 344, 116, 150, 111, 74, 90, 48, 66, 137, 134, 187, 
130, 186, 210, 44, 106, 66, 204, 100, 111, 34, 43, 83, 94, 70, 
104, 85, 43, 113, 94, 88, 110, 100, 43, 122, 61, 38, 90, 71, 
217, 180, 112, 84, 195, 77, 167, 203, 67, 204, 247, 221), Use = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No"), Colors = c("#A50F15", "#A50F15", "#A50F15", 
"#A50F15", "#A50F15", "#A50F15", "#DE2D26", "#DE2D26", "#DE2D26", 
"#DE2D26", "#DE2D26", "#DE2D26", "#FB6A4A", "#FB6A4A", "#FB6A4A", 
"#FB6A4A", "#FB6A4A", "#FB6A4A", "#FCAE91", "#FCAE91", "#FCAE91", 
"#FCAE91", "#FCAE91", "#FCAE91", "#FEE5D9", "#FEE5D9", "#FEE5D9", 
"#FEE5D9", "#FEE5D9", "#FEE5D9", "#3182BD", "#3182BD", "#3182BD", 
"#3182BD", "#3182BD", "#3182BD", "#9ECAE1", "#9ECAE1", "#9ECAE1", 
"#9ECAE1", "#9ECAE1", "#9ECAE1", "#DEEBF7", "#DEEBF7", "#DEEBF7", 
"#DEEBF7", "#DEEBF7", "#DEEBF7", "#31A354", "#31A354", "#31A354", 
"#31A354", "#31A354", "#31A354", "#A1D99B", "#A1D99B", "#A1D99B", 
"#A1D99B", "#A1D99B", "#A1D99B", "#E5F5E0", "#E5F5E0", "#E5F5E0", 
"#E5F5E0", "#E5F5E0", "#E5F5E0", "#756BB1", "#756BB1", "#756BB1", 
"#756BB1", "#756BB1", "#756BB1", "#BCBDDC", "#BCBDDC", "#BCBDDC", 
"#BCBDDC", "#BCBDDC", "#BCBDDC", "#EFEDF5", "#EFEDF5", "#EFEDF5", 
"#EFEDF5", "#EFEDF5", "#EFEDF5", "#E6550D", "#E6550D", "#E6550D", 
"#E6550D", "#E6550D", "#E6550D", "#FEE6CE", "#FEE6CE", "#FEE6CE", 
"#FEE6CE", "#FEE6CE", "#FEE6CE")), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to be able to help you, you should share the output of `dput(df_3UTR_ext_colors_simple)` at the end of your question - don't post pictures of your data. Also remove the code that is not relevant for your plot.

Comment: Thanks markus. Just made the edits as per your suggestions.